# Как сделать переадресацию сообщения из бота в чат?

Tags: python, telebot

Как реализовать переадресацию? Когда пользователь отправляет сообщение в боте, бот должен переадресовать его в отдельный чат для этого?

Comment: Попробуйте отправлять ссылку на пользователя. Например `@username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Мой ответ корректен, если вам нужно переадресовать сообщение от пользователя.*

Воспользуйтесь функцией *пересылки* сообщений.

```
tb.forward_message(to_chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id)
```

Либо, если вам нужно как-либо его форматировать, то измените message.text и воспользуйтесь отправкой сообщения по id.

```
bot.send_message(chat_id, message.text)
```